# refrigerator water line

Tags: water

I have to move a refregerator with Ice maker to a different room. There is no water line there. I am ok with out icemaker in that room. My concern is can I run a refregerator with ice maker with out a water line ? Does it cause any problem to the equipment ?

Comment: Mine has a shut of switch and is off do not use ice maker, and never had trouble

Answer (score 1):

We ran our fridge with the water disconnected for years without any problems.
What does the manual say?